# PHP - error Error fatal recuperable

Tags: php, mysql

hola a todos estoy queriendo filtrar un calendario por el usuario que inicio sesion,
pero me esta marcando este error

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

en la linea 34

esta es la forma que recupero el nombre del usuario que esta en sesion o se logeo.

```html
$usuario = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$sql="select Nombre from login where user_name ='$usuario' ";
$result= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
```

y esta es mi linea 34 donde realizo la consulta del calendario para filtrar.

```html
* Realizamos la consulta SQL */
$sql="select * from tareas where Auditor ='$result'";
$result= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) die("No hay registros para mostrar");
 
/* Desplegamos cada uno de los registros dentro de una tabla */  
echo "<table border=0 cellpadding=15 cellspacing=3>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error es por que [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) devuelve un objeto y tu quieres recorrerlo directamente, pero para ello debes llamarlo de otra forma así queda el código:

```
if($result->mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) die("No hay registros para mostrar");
```

fíjate que `$result` es tu variable y como es un objeto accedes a su función con el símbolo compuesto `->`

Creo que deberías mirar la documentación y ver como se maneja todo el asunto de la conexión, por ejemplo asi se llama según la documentación:

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* comprobar la conexión */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

La documentación te va a ayudar mucho saludos.

Answer (score 0):

### El problema

Antonio, el problema está en el `WHERE` de tu segunda consulta, ya que en el mismo estás usando la variable `$result` obtenida anteriormente:

<s>`$sql="select * from tareas where Auditor ='$result'";`</s>

y es que resulta que esa variable no es un valor, sino un objeto `mysqli_result` de ahí el mensaje de error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be
>   converted to string

### La solución

Tendrías que recuperar un valor válido para pasarlo en el `WHERE`, por ejemplo de este modo:

#### En la 1ª consulta:

- debes utilizar algún método para almacenar los resultados (aquí he usado `mysqli_fetch_assoc`)
- luego obtienes el valor de la columna `Nombre` en la variable `$nombre` que usarás más adelante en la 2ª consulta

Algo así:

```
$usuario = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$sql="select Nombre from login where user_name ='$usuario' ";
$result= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$arrDatos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$nombre=$arrDatos['Nombre'];
```

#### En la 2ª consulta:

- aquí lo único que tienes que cambiar es la variable `$result` que usabas antes, por la variable `$nombre`

Algo así:

```
* Realizamos la consulta SQL */
$sql="select * from tareas where Auditor ='$nombre'";
$result= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) die("No hay registros para mostrar");

/* Desplegamos cada uno de los registros dentro de una tabla */  
echo "<table border=0 cellpadding=15 cellspacing=3>";
```

---

### Nota sobre la seguridad:

Tu código es **altamente vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL**, una vez resuelto el presente problema, considera blindar tu código de ese tipo de ataques mediante el uso de consultas preparadas. Aquí mismo encontrarás información y ejemplos varios de cómo hacerlo.